# Typescript get generic function's return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to get return type of `fn` which is generic for my `errorbound` function.

I tried

```
type ErrorBound = <Fn extends Function>(Fn) => Promise<ReturnType<typeof Fn> | Error>;
export const errorBound: ErrorBound = async (fn) => {
 try {
  return await fn();
 } catch (e) {
  console.error("errorBound!!");
  console.error({ e });
   return e

 }
};
```

I want it be like

```
const foo = errorBound(() => 1) // foo is now Promise<number | Error>
```

But currently `foo` is `Promise<any>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const errorBound = <T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => T): T | Error => {
    try {
        return fn();
    } catch(e) {
        console.log({e})
        if (!(e instanceof Error)) return new Error(`Not an Error: ${e}`);
        return e;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgJwSBAhEBXMATGBeGAHgBUA+ACgDMwAuGcgOiYEMEBzCO5sATwG0AugEp8pGMSF1iMAD4wAokhSiYAbwBQMLTCgIeazdqMI4UDAjAxq5IQG5DWgL4xgzKMAAW5OCI1GjoJAgADZwDMEgbOSqcI5CDv4AlpT0AITeMImQUNzAcCApisgIQiImZhYwYHAA7gpKCOQABgByILDc9cV0ACQxjk12Ccam5pZw9kaO6o5AA)

- It looks easier to generize the return type rather than the function itself
- You don't need to `return await somePromise` it's equivalent to `return somePromise`
- `e` is not always an error, it's valid JS to `throw 10` or `throw 'not an Error object'`, so I added a check

Answer (score 0):

```js
type F = <T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => T) => Promise<T | Error>
const f: F = async (fn) => {
    return fn()
}
const ff = () => Math.random()
const n = f(ff) // Promise<number | Error>
```